# How to instanciate a NMARoute object from GPX file

Tags: ios, here-api

We are working with the iOS Premium HereMaps SDK. Our basic question is how to instantiate a `NMARoute` object from a quite detailed GPX file. This object should be used for a custom turn-by-turn navigation. At the moment we take the following steps:

1. Create an array of `NMAGeoCoordinates` objects from the GPX file
2. Create an array of `NMAWaypoint`s
3. Call `[NMACoreRouter calculateRouteWithStops:]`

Unfortunately we are facing multiple limitations:

- The `[NMACoreRouter calculateRouteWithStops:]` method limits the number of waypoints. Although we have a GPX file that is detailed enough to create the whole route we have to cherry pick waypoints and let the here service calculate the route again. This process does not ensure we will get exactly the route we had in the GPX file.
- NMAWaypoints cause a "You reached your stopover" voice call out during the turn by turn navigation every time a waypoint is reached. We know that it is possible to use `NMAViaWaypoint` as type but this is unsuitable for us because `NMAViaWaypoint`s will be dismissed during a reroute process which could happen during the navigation. Moreover stopovers will cause a break in the navigation e.g. in the distances displayed.
- For some GPS points that are located at the middle of a crossing the HereMaps routing calculation sometimes chooses a different route than intended. This is again due to the problem that HereMaps want to calculate the route by its own, despite the fact that we have a detailed GPX file containing the route.

What we are actually looking for is a better way to get a `NMARoute` object from a GPX file. To our surprise there is a [REST endpoint](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/locations_data_to_route/match-gpx-data-to-a-route) provided by the HereMaps SDK to convert a GPX file to json data but unfortunately no way to feed this data into the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will sadly not work with the current HERE iOS SDK. There is a tight coupling of TbT Navigation and routing, so Navigation can only work with the internal route engine at the moment.

Some background:

Imagine you derive from your pre-calculated route while navigating (it might even happen when you don't derive, e.g. due to GPS jumps, wrong mapmatching in complex situations, temporary loss of signal, if you start in unmapped or private roadnetworks, and so on) navigation will ask routing to re-calculate. And what if your GPX trace is not matching the road network and mapdata in the iOS MobileSDK based application ? So your trace tells guidance to drive somewhere, where no road is available anymore ? Guidance would refuse and force recalculation. And in your case you most probably don't want traffic optimized navigation, but what to do with blocked roads (so not just slow free flow speed, but fully blocked)? I'd suggest to enable optimization here - but that would also not work with static GPX traces.

So as you already said, the better solution is to recalculate locally a route that's very close to your traces, but takes the local mapdata and constrains into account.

The limitations you mention are correct, but:

- The Waypoint limit has been completely remove in SDK 3.6 now. But please still keep care with the number of waypoints, especially with a number > 500 and complex segments in between these waypoints.
- Did you try to use NMAAudioManager delegate to intercept the audio output ? https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/protocolnmaaudiomanagerdelegate-p.html#topic-apiref
- As described above, there are many reasons why the route derives. Sometimes it's due to mapdata, sometimes due to the calculation constains. 100% reconstruction might be tricky (sometimes probably you are right with the GPX trace, but in some situations the HERE SDK might be right), so try to play around with the number of waypoints and routing options to get as close as possible.